# Show/Hide div element with one button

Tags: jquery, html

I have recently been diving into jquery and loved how you could show/hide elements when an event is triggered. I tried adding a simple feature to my test website that will show Login Form when the login button is clicked and then hide the form if the button is clicked again, however; the jquery function I am using only works once (when I click the button and display the form) but after the form is displayed if I try to click the button again nothing happens.

Jquery Code:

```
function displayLoginBox(){


if ($("#login_Box_Div:hidden")){

        $("#login_Box_Div").show();
        $("#buttonLogin").css('color', '#FF0');

}
else if($("#login_Box_Div:visible")){

        $("#login_Box_Div").hide(); 
        $("#buttonLogin").css('color','white');
}
}
```

HTML button code:

```
<h3> <a href= "#">Pictio  </a> <button id = "buttonLogin" onclick = "displayLoginBox()">LogIn</button></h3>
```

HTML div code:

```
<div id = "login_Box_Div"> 
        <form name = "myform" > 
            <input type = "text" name = "username" placeholder = "Username"  />
            <input type = "password" name = "password" placeholder= "Password" />
            <input type = "submit" id = "submitLogin" />
        </form>

</div>
```

I have a feeling that the jquery script only runs once and then is finished, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Where is the HTML for the `login_Box_Div`? Without it, you'll never pass the `:visible` test.

Comment: Sorry bout that, I added the div in the code above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `.toggle()`

```
$('#buttonLogin').on('click', function(e){
    $("#login_Box_Div").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('class1')
});​

.class1
{
     color: orange;
}​
```

You can use `toggleClass()` to toggle the class for the button

**[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/utaxK/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, I tried using .toggle but it doesn't make the div appear.

Comment: Wow, cool site you took me to! Thanks! I got it now :)) But one more thing... If i were to want to make the form hidden initially should I do this with $(document).ready(function(e){ $(this).hide();});?

Comment: set this in the CSS  form{ display: none  }  .. If the form has a id then assign the Class to that id

Comment: @cipherous .. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: Hello again haha I thought it was working bc it worked fine on the FIDDLE link but then when I implement the same exact code in my file it doesnt work. I tried experimenting a little bit to try and find the issue and found out that my jquery stuff only works when I either do <button onclick = "function()"> but when I try to access html elements using the $(this).on('click') it doesnt work... I'm thinking maybe it is the jquery file i downloaded but i am not sure, because even when I copy your code exactly from fiddle it won't work. Is there any other jquery file I need to link?

Comment: If you are calling the function that way then     this points to window and not the current event

Comment: Why don't you move the event handler to your js file as a whole

Comment: It still doesn't work, this is so weird to me because I am using the exact code from the FIDDLE you showed me, which works great on that, but when I try it doesn't want to work! lol frustrated

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18827/discussion-between-cipherous-and-sushanth)

Comment: Hi thank you for this code, but i have a question: is it possible to make it not appear first, then after which use toggle?

Comment: Just add the class to the element. that should take care of not displaying it.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to use inline javascript.

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/utakef/5/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('#buttonLogin').click(function(){
   $('#login_Box_Div').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

```
$('#buttonLogin').on('click', function(e){
    $("#login_Box_Div").toggle();
    var color=$("#login_Box_Div").is(':hidden') ? '#FF0' : 'white';
    $("#buttonLogin").css('color', color);
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/VqwCU/1/).

### Update:

Or using `togglrClass` you may try this

```
$('#buttonLogin').on('click', function(e){
    $("#login_Box_Div").toggle();
    $("#buttonLogin").toggleClass('whiteColor yelolowCollor');
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/VqwCU/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
function displayLoginBox(elem){

 $("#login_Box_Div").toggle();
 $(elem).toggleClass('login_clicked');

}
```

CSS

```
#buttonLogin{color: #fff;}
.login_clicked{color: #FF0 !important;}
```

HTML

```
<h3> <a href= "#">Pictio  </a> <button id = "buttonLogin" onclick = "displayLoginBox(this)">LogIn</button></h3>
```

This approach also changes the login button color.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this:](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
function displayLoginBox(){
    $("#login_Box_Div").toggle(function(e) {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            $("#login_Box_Div").show();
            $("#buttonLogin").css('color', '#FF0');
        }
        else {
            $("#login_Box_Div").hide(); 
            $("#buttonLogin").css('color','white');
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:hidden` and `:visible` selectors are filters, not Boolean methods.

What that means is: when you're testing

```
if ($("#login_Box_Div:hidden")){
```

...what you get from `$("#login_Box_Div:hidden")` is a jQuery object -- which ALWAYS exists, and will ALWAYS return true, even if there's nothing in it.

What you need to do is test the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length) of that jQuery object. If it's zero, the jQuery object is empty:

```
if ($("#login_Box_Div:hidden").length){ // zero is false, greater than zero is true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ThwFs/

Alternatively, use the [`.is(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/is) method, which DOES return a Boolean (true/false) value:

```
if ($("#login_Box_Div").is(":hidden")){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ThwFs/2/

While there are many ways to streamline your code, this is the answer to the actual problem you were having.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('login_Box_Div').is(':hidden')` and `$('login_Box_Div').is(':visible')`

You also shouldn't use inline javascript.
Here is a jsfiddle of it working http://jsfiddle.net/MrsW8/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code if you like, it helped me achieve the same.

```
$("button").click(function(){
$("div").toggle(function(e) {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            $("div").show();
            $("button").css('color', 'red');
        }
        else {
            $("div").hide(); 
            $("button").css('color','white');
        };
    });
});
```

I am just using a single div and a single button with no id.
Hope it helps your cause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VueJs, and it's working hide/show in a single button. When I click on the button it will toggle. 
**For Example:-** 
If show is false then it will assign true.
If show is true then it will assign false.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 v-if="show">Show</h1>
        <h1 v-else>Hide</h1>
        <button @click="show =! show">Toggle Heading</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Home',
    data() {
        return {
            show: true 
        }
    }
}
</script>
```