# Hide and show a comment form with a click

Tags: jquery, comments

I am trying to make the WordPress comment form not show all the time, but to open when clicking on a button. The below code I tried works great.

The problem is that I also want the form to hide by clicking the same button. Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
<a href="#" ID="Leave_a_comment">Click here to leave a Comment</a><
<div id="comment_form_wrapper" style="display: none;">
  <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Leave_a_comment').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#comment_form_wrapper').show();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Change `show()` to `toggle()`

Comment: That is correct! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/Hide div element with one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145653/show-hide-div-element-with-one-button)