# Wordpress custom field with 3 linked data points

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF select field in Wordpress, that I use the label AND value field to display on the front-end.

**Select choice**

```
02 : Level 2: This is my level 2 copy
```

On the front-end I am able to display these split into table cells using PHP explode on the ":"

```
<tr>
<td>02<td>
<td>Level 2</td>
<td>This is my level 2 copy</td>
</tr>
```

The select field is really clunky and very hard to update across hundreds of these.

Is there a better way or a better field I can use to do this and keep them linked together as the user will select these from 1-10.

Comment: By using js you can show hide the your options 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145653/show-hide-div-element-with-one-button

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom post type and add title, post content and custom fields as required.

Comment: These will not be linked together though, but separate posts. I am looking for it to be used as a long dropdown in the admin. So there are 30 select options in the dropdown for example.